# local python server + xampp + android connection

Tags: android, python, mysql, server, xampp

My python server works with xampp on local. Apache port 80,443 and MySql 3306.
Server works on web. I use http://127.0.0.1:5000/login for request, but android device doesn't see this server on web browser and app. They are on same network. I tried ip 192..../login , 10.0.2.2:5000/login etc. How can I use my android app with local python server in xampp. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried disabling firewall?

Comment: Yes, I tried. Also, I tried disabling antivirus.